# Vertical Elastic Query Azure Database unable to authenticate

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database

I did create an External Datasource, identical to the guide described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/384520cf4e124ef9d6f8dcff8ed4200d4d2e1f9d/articles/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical.md) .The process is pretty simple, so just for illustration.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION ...
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ...
```

Not covered in the article is how to create login and user. On the *master* database I did execute

```
CREATE LOGIN <externaldbname> WITH PASSWORD = '<somepassword1>'; 
CREATE USER externaldbname FOR LOGIN externaldbname;
```

And on the *externaldb*

```
CREATE USER externaldbname FOR LOGIN externaldbname;
```

Then continued with the guide

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ...
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ..
```

All executed successfully. Now when I try to select something from the external database, this error is raised

> Msg 46823, Level 16, State 2, Line 10 Error retrieving data from one
>   or more shards.  The underlying error message received was: Cannot
>   open database externaldb requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user externaldbname.

I am able to login with the given credential to the *externaldb* if using  Visual Studio. Is there any special permission that needs to be granted or what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. The database name in the external data source definition was not the same (typo) as actual database name.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials you created, do they have read access to the remote database that you are trying to access?

If the permissions are all fine, then can you email me your setup details along with the T-SQL statements you used at SDoomra(at)Microsoft(dot)com?

Thanks

Silvia Doomra

Comment: yes I did run GRANT SELECT TO externaldbname; on the external server. See the production Query in your email.

Comment: Issue resolved. The database name in the external data source definition was not the same (typo) as actual database name.